# Animation nodes - Replicate splines - random bevel size

Tags: animation-nodes, bevel, splines

Id like to build set of spline with applied vector noise to simulate lightnings. I have followed Chris.P. tutorial and its done.
But I have two problems.

How can I set different Bevel Depth on each spline? It seems like Curve Object Output doesn't support list, only single value.

Second question is how can I set specific Bevel Depth for each point but on each spline specifically?
It can be random, but each spline should have different random sizes.
Third question is there any node which can from input 1,2,3 make 111,222,333?

Thanks a lot.

I want to control thickness of each spline

[image: nodes]

[image: Lightning]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for your third question. It takes four AN-nodes if want a number as a result. If a text will do you can skip the last node.
[image]

Comment: Interresting, solution, but its not that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think, I got solution.
I don't know how I did it but it seems works ..)

[image]

I still don't understand  How Input loop works and why there is "Spline input" and "Curve output" (naming) but the tool is pretty powerful.