# how to replicate spline and randomize bevel

Tags: animation-nodes, bevel, instances, splines

I would like to randomize bevel size of the replicated spline.

It look like Curve Object Output - Bevel Depth -  doesn't work with list of numbers.

Is there any other options?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I don’t know much about geometry nodes, but I noticed the “get list element“ node has nothing input as an index, and will thus always pick the first element of the list. Is this intentional?

Comment: it is animation nodes ;) not geometry nodes.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

[image]

result (i just took an arbitrary curve):

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Chris, it helped me, I have solved my problem in other question with the Lightnings. [lightnings] (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/212692/animation-nodes-replicate-splines-random-bevel-size/212977#212977)